# Datatype map: Query key names and return values

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am trying to query an XML map (result of parsing JSON file with json-to-xml) using key name, to get out key value during "for-each".

I am able to query with key index, see test-1. Test-2 and Test-3 fails but I think I have the syntax wrong in relation to how to handle queries towards an XML map.

I am leaving the test-1 activated, and comment-out the test-2/test-3, since that setup shows the wanted result. Balance is not used but kept just to secure that it is not passed to result.

**JSON:**

```
<data>
{
"period": {
      "0": {"startDate": "2016-01-01","endDate": "2016-12-31"},
      "1": {"startDate": "2015-01-01","endDate": "2015-12-31"}
    },

"balance": {
      "0": {"instant": "2016-01-01"},
      "1": {"instant": "2015-01-01"}
    }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:root="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:periods="http://www.example.com/2"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <root:report>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
        </root:report>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process "period" -->

    <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'period']">

      <xsl:for-each select="./*">

            <periods:startDate>

          <!-- Test [1] -->
          <!-- Extract startDate value by index -->
          <xsl:value-of select="./*[1]"/>

          <!-- Test [2] -->
          <!-- Extract startDate value by name -->
          <!-- <xsl:value-of select="startDate"/> -->

          <!-- Test [3] -->
          <!-- Extract startDate by function map:get -->
          <!-- <xsl:variable name="$startDate" select="What to put here?"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="map:get($startDate)"/> -->

        </periods:startDate>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Wanted result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root:report xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
             xmlns:periods="http://www.example.com/2"
             xmlns:root="http://www.example.com/1">
   <periods:startDate>2016-01-01</periods:startDate>
   <periods:startDate>2015-01-01</periods:startDate>
</root:report>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the for loop, if you were to return the Map XML structure: `<xsl:sequence select="."/>`  you will see that it looks like this:

```
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="0">
  <string key="startDate">2016-01-01</string>
  <string key="endDate">2016-12-31</string>
</map>
```

So, for your second test, in order to extract the startDate, select the element by the `@key` attribute:

```
<!-- Test [2] -->
<!-- Extract startDate value by name -->
<xsl:value-of select="*[@key='startDate']"/>
```